# C++ - Matrix class copy constructor

Tags: c++, matrix, swap

I'm trying to set up a Matrix class and was wondering about the copy constructor. I have read through the [copy-and-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) and [operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading). I can't decide which is more efficient:

Solution 1:

```
Matrix<T>::Matrix(const Matrix<T>& rhs) {
    Matrix<T> temp(rhs);
    this.swap(temp);
}

Matrix<T>::void swap(Matrix<T> rhs) 
: dx(rhs.dx), dy(rhs.dy) {
  allocArrays();
  for (int i=0; i<dx; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j<dy; ++j) {
      p[i][j] = rhs.p[i][j];
    }
  }
}
```

or take the simple route and simply use

Solution 2:

```
Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& rhs) 
: dx(m.dx), dy(m.dy) {
allocArrays();
  for (int i=0; i<dx; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j<dy; ++j) {
      p[i][j] = rhs.p[i][j];
    }
  }
}
```

Matrix Header:

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

#include <vector>

template <typename T> class Matrix {
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> matrix;
    void allocArrays();  
    unsigned int dx, dy; // dimensions of x and y
    long **p; // pointer to pointer for long int

public:
    Matrix();
    ~Matrix();
    Matrix(const Matrix<T>& rhs);
    Matrix(unsigned xSize, unsigned ySize);
    Matrix<T>& operator=(const Matrix<T>& rhs);

    // Adding below code to showcase what else will be happening with the Matrices

    // Matrix mathematical operations                                                                                                                                                                                               
    Matrix<T> operator+(const Matrix<T>& rhs);
    Matrix<T>& operator+=(const Matrix<T>& rhs);
    Matrix<T> operator-(const Matrix<T>& rhs);
    Matrix<T>& operator-=(const Matrix<T>& rhs);
    Matrix<T> operator*(const Matrix<T>& rhs);
    Matrix<T>& operator*=(const Matrix<T>& rhs);
    Matrix<T> transpose();

    // Matrix/scalar operations                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    Matrix<T> operator+(const T& rhs);
    Matrix<T> operator-(const T& rhs);
    Matrix<T> operator*(const T& rhs);
    Matrix<T> operator/(const T& rhs);

    // Matrix/vector operations                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    std::vector<T> operator*(const std::vector<T>& rhs);
    std::vector<T> diag_vec();

    // Access the individual elements                                                                                                                                                                                               
    T& operator()(const unsigned& row, const unsigned& col);
    const T& operator()(const unsigned& row, const unsigned& col) const;
};

#include "matrix.cpp"
#endif
```

Matrix CPP file:

```
#ifndef _MATRIX_CPP
#define _MATRIX_CPP

#include "matrix.h"
#include <iostream>

// Default Constructor 
Matrix<T>::Matrix() : Matrix(1, 1) {}

// Parameter Constructor                                                                                                                                                      
template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(unsigned xSize, unsigned ySize) 
    : dx(xSize), dy(ySize) {

    allocArrays();

    for (int i = 0; i < dx; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dy; j++) {
            p[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

// Copy Constructor @ which is most effective way of doing this                                                                                                                                                          
template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(const Matrix<T>& rhs) {}

Matrix<T>::void allocArrays() {
    p = new long*[dx];
    for (int i = 0; i < dx; i++)
        p[i] = new long[dy];
}
```

Comment: `I can't decide which is more efficient` So write some code to measure which is more efficient.  BTW, what is that `long **p` member supposed to accomplish?

Comment: solution 1 is infinitely recursive

Comment: The copy-and-swap idiom is for implementing the assignment operator, not the copy constructor. It uses the copy constructor.

Comment: What I don't understand is that you have `matrix` as a vector, yet you resorted to using `p`. If you didn't use `p` and instead used `matrix` to store your values, then there would be no need for a user-defined copy/assignment operator.

Comment: 31 questions and only 5 were acceptable?  Suggest reviewing posts and expand the count of answers that are acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

The first solution implies a recursive constructor call and will never work :

```
Matrix<T>::Matrix(const Matrix<T>& rhs) {
    Matrix<T> temp(rhs);
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // Recursive call here
    this.swap(temp);
}
```

As for any potential performance difference, always use a profiler on a decent set of test cases. If your swap is correctly implemented, you will see with any decent compiler that the creation of the temporary for the swap has a negligible cost compared to the allocation/filling of the matrix.

**Note:**

As your links show, the copy-and-swap idiom is implemented by the assignment operator (which calls the copy constructor), not the copy constructor itself.